# How to pass IWebBrowser2::Navigate2 arguments?

Tags: c++, winapi, webview, com

I want to implement Internet Explorer webview control on my window.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61586644/6337792) answer, on how to do that.

There is a problem: `Navigate2` method from the answer is different from the headers I have. In the posters’s code, seems it has only one argument, and maybe others are by default, but I have 5 arguments with the stupidest thing I have ever met - `VARIANT` type variables (also, in poster’s code it is `_variant_t` which is undefined for me).

Probably I will never understand the sEiFe logic, why to make instead of `Navigate2(wchar_t *,...)` cool stuff `VARIANT *` (I know about `Navigate` method), but can anyone provide an example of calling that method.

This full code

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Ole2.h>
#include "resource.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <atlbase.h> //activex
#include <atlwin.h> //windows
#include <atlcom.h>
#include "exdisp.h"
#include <comutil.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "comsuppw.lib")

//This will load the browser dll then library and will generate headers
//All the declarations will be in the namespace SHDocVw
//#import "shdocvw.dll"
using namespace std;

class CMyDialog : public CAxDialogImpl<CMyDialog>
{
public:
enum { IDD = IDD_DIALOG1 };

BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CMyDialog)
MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_INITDIALOG, OnInitDialog)
COMMAND_HANDLER(IDCANCEL, BN_CLICKED, OnBnCancel)
COMMAND_HANDLER(IDOK, BN_CLICKED, OnBnOk)
END_MSG_MAP()
CComPtr<IWebBrowser2>  ctrl;
LRESULT OnInitDialog(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
{
// Do some initialization code
HRESULT hr;
//IDC_EXPLORER_TEST is the ID of your control
GetDlgControl(IDC_EXPLORER_TEST, __uuidof(ctrl), (void**)&ctrl);

VARIANT address;
address.vt = VT_BSTR;
address.bstrVal = SysAllocString(L"google.com");

VARIANT empty;
empty.vt = VT_EMPTY;

hr = ctrl->Navigate2(&address, &empty, &empty, &empty, &empty);

SysFreeString(address.bstrVal);

/* 

Also fails

_variant_t a = SysAllocString(L"google.com");
VARIANT f;
f.vt = VT_I2;
f.iVal = navBrowserBar;
_variant_t fr = SysAllocString(L"_self");
_variant_t h = SysAllocString(L" ");

hr = ctrl->Navigate2(&a, &f, &fr, &h, &h);
*/
  
LRESULT res = CAxDialogImpl<CMyDialog>::OnInitDialog(uMsg, wParam, lParam, bHandled);
return 0;
}
public:
LRESULT OnBnCancel(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
{
EndDialog(IDCANCEL);
return 0;
}
LRESULT OnBnOk(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
{
EndDialog(IDOK);
return 0;
}
};
CComModule _Module;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE,HINSTANCE,LPSTR,int)
{
CMyDialog dlg;
dlg.DoModal();

return 0;
}
```

Returns an exception at method call because of `0x0` read violation.

Comment: try adress.bstrVal = ::SysAllocString(L"google.com");
...
::SysFreeString

Comment: @wtom I tried without `SysFreeString` it also returns the exception. Should I try `SysFreeString`?

Comment: Do you allocate adress.bstrVal with SysAllocString call?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/allocating-and-releasing-memory-for-a-bstr?view=vs-2019

Comment: We'll need complete code from you. You're missing `_variant_t` because you're not including the same headers, for instance.

Comment: @wtom, yes I tried that.

Comment: @wtom: Would be far easier to use `_bstr_t` from `<comdef.h>`.

Comment: @MSalters added the full code

Comment: did you check ctrl?

Comment: @wtom yeah, it is null. But why?

Comment: hard to say. wrong id? isn't created (yet)? mb looking into GetDlgControl return value will help?

Comment: @wtom, yeah, by some reason in my `resourse.h` file I have two different IDs for explorer. Thank You for help

Comment: A really important lesson here. Always implement error checking code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you failed to check if `GetDlgControl` succeeded. When it fails, `ctrl` has an unspecified value and might be null.

Of course, that leaves the question why it would fail, but that's another issue.